# John the Ripper exclude incremental mode from another incremental mode

Tags: passwords

I want to crack an 8 characters password. First, I tried the incremental mode digits, but I did not find the password. So now I know it's not all digits password. I want to use lowernum incremental mode instead.

Is it possible to tell John the Ripper to exclude all digits passwords?

Comment: So you want to use lowercase and numerics, but skip passwords containing all numerics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official manual](http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/MODES.shtml):

> As of version 1.8.0, pre-defined incremental modes are "ASCII" (all 95 printable ASCII characters), "LM_ASCII" (for use on LM hashes), "Alnum" (all 62 alphanumeric characters), "Alpha" (all 52 letters), "LowerNum" (lowercase letters plus digits, for 36 total), "UpperNum" (uppercase letters plus digits, for 36 total), "LowerSpace" (lowercase letters plus space, for 27 total), "Lower" (lowercase letters), "Upper" (uppercase letters), and "Digits" (digits only).

I suppose you want the 'Lower' charset. You can download these extra charsets [here](http://www.openwall.com/john/) (the download you need is called '***John the Ripper 1.8.x extra charset files archive***').

In case you do not use the 1.8 version, you can still download the extra charsets, but you'll also have to modify your john.conf file. Add the following section somewhere in the 'Incremental modes' section (modified minLength and maxLength, as you only want to crack an 8-character password):

`[Incremental:Lower]
File = *pathToLowerCharset*
MinLen = 8
MaxLen = 8
CharCount = 26`

And finally:

```
john -i=Lower myhashedpwds
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [crunch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/crunch-wordlist/files/crunch-wordlist/) to generate wordlists that contain at least one lowercase letter.

Then feed this wordlist into John use the `--wordlist` option:

```
john hashes.txt --wordlist=generated_from_crunch.txt
```